# Hangman (with a cinnamon roll) [tkinter]

Tags: python, tkinter

This hangman game was one of the first games I have ever made, and I've recently been going back through my old programs and spicing them up a bit. In this one I added a cinnamon roll :D. However, when the code runs, it just delays a bit at the end, then quits, no cinnamon roll. I have tried googling my problem, and what I am trying to do, but I know no one who if familiar with tkinter. The problem is happening towards the bottom.Here is the code:

```
import random
import time
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Hangman!")
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=700, height=700)
canvas.pack()
cinnamonroll = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\cinnamonroll.gif')
hangmanpic0 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\hangmanpic0.gif')
hangmanpic1 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\hangmanpic1.gif')
hangmanpic2 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\hangmanpic2.gif')
hangmanpic3 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\hangmanpic3.gif')
hangmanpic4 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\hangmanpic4.gif')
hangmanpic5 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\hangmanpic5.gif')
hangmanpic6 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\hangmanpic6.gif')
hangmanpics = (hangmanpic0, hangmanpic1, hangmanpic2, hangmanpic3, \
    hangmanpic4, hangmanpic5, hangmanpic6)
words = ("taffy", "guitar", "talking", "retire", "fanning", "news", \
    "moon", "sunny", "driving", "prevent", "stick", "images", \
    "trees", "reading", "books", "character", "doctor", "telephone", \
    "license", "braces", "giraffe", "spotted", "exiting", \
    "animation", "flower", "assassination", "mother", "tomato", \
    "fruity", "school")
word = random.choice(words)
progress = "-" * len(word)
wrong = 0
lettersguessed = []
print("Are you ready to play hangman!?")
time.sleep(1)
while wrong < 6 and progress != word:
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=hangmanpics[wrong])
    print("You have used %s out of 6 guesses" %  wrong)
    print("You have guessed these letters: %s" % lettersguessed)
    print(progress)
    guess = input("Guess a letter. ")
    guess = guess.lower()
    while guess in lettersguessed:
        guess = input("You already guessed %s. Guess another letter!" % guess)
        guess = guess.lower()
    lettersguessed.append(guess)
    if guess in word:
        print("Correct, good job!")
        new = ""
        for i in range(0, len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += progress[i]
                progress = new
            else:
                print("NOPE! Sad face.")
                wrong += 1
if wrong == 6:
    print(hangmanpics[wrong])
    print("You got hanged!!! *triple snap*")
else:
    print("You win!")
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=cinnamonroll)
    time.sleep(2)
print("The word was %s! Thanks for playing!" % word)
```

Comment: Looks like you need a `tk.mainloop()` if nothing else.

Comment: Note that you have to capsule your code in a function/method an run it via the `after` method.

Comment: the code has a syntax error and can't run (two else's after the if).  was that second one supposed to be dedented?

Comment: Thanks tdelaney, the reason it's "working by luck" is because I made this program a LONG time ago and it was one of my first ones, so its kind of sloppy. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using tkinter in a strange way (no Application or mainloop). tkinter events aren't firing and updates aren't happening in a timely manner. It turns out that your game was only working by luck. Whenever you call `input()`, tkinter kicks its processing loop and things display. I have no idea what that magic is, but for instance, your original images only display after an `input()` (you can add a sleep before to check for yourself). You can get your final display to work by adding

```
...
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=cinnamonroll)
tk.update_idletasks() 
time.sleep(2)
```

Do the same after all of your tk updates and sleep a little more than 2 seconds - it's not that fast!